# HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider is not working am doing incorrect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss, html-agility-pack

Asp.net 4.5 , IIS 8

The sanitizer even not removing this simple script

```
<script>alert('error')</script>
```

Ok here my config

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessageBody" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="500px" runat="server"
 CssClass="MessageSendArea" MaxLength="4000" ClientIDMode="Static" />

        <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="htmlEditorExtender1" TargetControlID="txtMessageBody"
                    runat="server" DisplaySourceTab="True">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
                        <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
                        <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
                        <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
                        <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
                        <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
                        <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
                        <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
                        <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
                        <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
                        <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
                        <ajaxToolkit:SelectAll />
                        <ajaxToolkit:UnSelect />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Delete />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
                        <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
                        <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
                        <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
                        <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
                        <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
                        <ajaxToolkit:HorizontalSeparator />
                    </Toolbar>
                </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Here my webconfig

```
  <configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web">
  <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

```
  <trust level="Full"/>
<sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"/>
  </providers>
</sanitizer>
```

here my check

```
        if (htmlEditorExtender1.SanitizerProvider == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("PostNewPM.aspx");
    }
```

Here the result i get when i post the above alert script message

```
&lt;script&gt;alert('error')&lt;/script&gt;
```

when it is decoded to display to user

```
<script>alert('error')</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the SanitizerProvider attribute as follows:

```
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="htmlEditorExtender1" 
    TargetControlID="txtMessageBody"
    runat="server" DisplaySourceTab="True" 
    SanitizerProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
```